# Number of notifications in the bell icon?

Tags: notification

In the salesforce documentation It mentioned that it will show only 20 notifications in the bell Icon, but I see more than 20 notifications.
can some one confirm how many notifications in the bell icon.

**In-app notifications keep users aware of relevant activity while they’re using the Salesforce app. By tapping Notification icon, a user can view the 20 most recent notifications received within the last 90 days.**

Answer (score 0):

I believe you are referring to [this documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.salesforce1appadmin.meta/salesforce1appadmin/s1_admin_guide_notifications.htm)   which is correct as it mentions a user can view the 20 most recent notifications within the salesforce1 mobile app. Those are In-app notifications.

You will see only 20 notifications in the mobile app from the bell icon. Hope this answers your query.

Comment: @user91936 Does this answer your query or do you have any follow up questions.Thanks